# SQL Server Bulk Insert won't import text file but DTS does

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

SQL Server Bulk Insert of text file produces 0 results, no error file and no imported data (rows). I am using a format file.

I have used the DTS function of SQL and successfully imported the data (SSMS Task). I have used BCP (command line) to successfully export and create the format file. I have used that format file with Bulk Insert to import the exported data using the format file. I have viewed my source data in Notepad++ showing all characters to ensure I have the correct column and row terminators.

```
BULK INSERT [schema].[tablename]
FROM 'FullyQualifiedFileName'
WITH (
      FORMATFILE = 'FullyQualifiedFileName'
     ,KEEPNULLS
     ,FIRSTROW = 2
     ,ERRORFILE = 'FullyQualifiedFilename'
     )
```

No error file is generated, no error is displayed and no data is imported.

I have been 'beating' on this for 2 days searching the hallowed halls of Google U endlessly. The source data is pipe-delimited (|) and I have confirmed through Notepad++ that the EndOfRow is a CR/LF. When I EXPORT the data via BCP, the resulting text file has a number of fields showing as `...|NULL|NULL|...` whereas my source file is `...|||.`

This learning experience is in aid of trying to develop a core SSIS package that will import multiple different flat files into multiple different SQL tables all 'mapped' correctly by use of the format files - that is the long distance destination. For now - I can't figure out why I can't BULK INSERT my sample data file.

I'm a technology 'generalist' having taught myself coding in numerous different languages and scripts. SQL Server is relatively new to me and the nuances of BULK INSERT and SSIS are challenging. I have worked through all the errors that I kept getting thrown up until this point - no errors... no data.

Comment: Did you use the exact same format file for `BULK INSERT` as you did for `bcp.exe` on the command line? My first guess would be that the format file doesn't contain the correct `FIELDTERMINATOR` and/or `ROWTERMINATOR` values.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that the file paths suppled to `bulk insert`, `formatfile` and `errorfile` are all relative to the SQL server instance. It won't work if you specify `C:\Tablename.psv`, `C:\Tablename.fmt` and `C:\Tablename.err` and those files are sitting on your workstation.

Comment: I used the same format file that I created via the bcp.exe on the command line for importing the data via BULK INSERT. Of course - if I import what I exported - it works fine. If I import my test file - it fails. I have not done a file compare on the test file vs the exported file - but visually, there exported file has explicit NULL between the pipe (|) delimiters. I am working on a local copy of SQLEXPRESS so all paths are local

Comment: I finally abandoned BULK INSERT and decided I can accomplish what I want through BCP.exe. After many hours of beating on this solution - I finally got it to work. The process I used was:
1) create a sample of my data (making sure I maintained text encoding)
2) using SSMS/DTS - imported the sample data
3) Using BCP create a format file
4) Export my data using the format file
5) Spend 2 hours trying to import the JUST exported data using the format file
6) figure out that the column labels in the format file are completely ignored- quotes around column labels with spaces doesn't work

Comment: 7) Remove the quote marks and just remove the space characters from the labels
8) Import exported data using modified format file - success
9) Import sample data using modified format file - success
10) Import full file using modified format file - success
11) import sample data using BULK INSERT with format file - success
12) Import full file using BULK INSERT with format file - failure (who cares now)